# Deriving a (generalized) Sequence from a Proper Sequence

Tags: common-lisp, sequence

A number of the Common Lisp sequence functions take a *proper sequence* as an input and return a *sequence* as output. Starting with a *proper sequence*, how could the function not return another *proper sequence*? Example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(mapcan #'rest (list (list 0 1 2) (cons :a :b)))
=> (1 2 . :b)
```

... but it is true that most of the time you can expect to have proper sequences as a result; functions might be underspecified for various reasons (cost to implementers, etc).

By the way, notice that [`NCONC`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_nconc.htm) is specified to return a list (at least in the HyperSpec), but the formal definition as given in the same page allows to have non-lists as a result, e.g. `(nconc nil 2)` is 2. This incomplete over-approximation of the type of result (in the signature, not the actual description of the function) contaminates all other results:

```
(mapcan #'rest (list (list) (cons 1 2)))
=> 2
```

See also [*Proposed ANSI Changes*](https://www.cliki.net/Proposed%20ANSI%20Changes) and [*ANSI Clarifications and Errata*](https://www.cliki.net/ANSI%20Clarifications%20and%20Errata).

Comment: Interesting. If I'm understanding correctly, this could not happen with any of the destructive sequence functions (delete, nsubstitute, etc)?

Comment: Yes, the behaviour of those functions are sufficently well specified that there is no room for cases where the resulting sequence is not proper. If you want a formal proof, there is none, but that seems pretty reasonable to assume.